# Windows service TCP client monitor

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I'm building a Windows tcp client service in C# that listens to remote tcp server that sends out status messages whenever there is an event. Also, I can verify the connection by sending request-reply message to the server. Right now I spun primary thread in the `OnStart()` method like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _worker = new Thread(DoWork);
    _worker.Start();
}
```

Within `DoWork`, I define new thread `check_conn`

```
private void DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        ....
        client = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                check_conn = new Thread(CheckConnection);
                check_conn.Start();
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In my `check_conn` thread, I basically send period request message to server and receive reply back.

```
private void CheckConnection()
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Are you alive");

            stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(1 * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I been running this service for sometime and it seems to be working fine. My concern is, is this the right way to do it? I mean is there a better way to check the connection than the way I have implemented here (having a thread within a thread)? Should I use the one `NetworkStream` for both threads or is it okay to do it like I have?

Also, I had some challenge stopping the service. I have `stream.Read()` method that reads status updates from server. This is a blocking call. To, break this, in my `onStop()` method, I `close()` the `client` and set `ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent` and wait for thread `_worker` to end by calling `Join()` method on it. The issue is, if I don't specify timespan on `Join()` method, the service status gets stuck on stopping and never stops. If I specify timespan, it stops:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    try
    {
        client.Close();
        _shutdownEvent.Set();
        hli_worker.Join(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I don't see you making any attempt at message framing here - which may or may not be an issue to you. TCP is an *endless stream of bytes*, not messages. So if you're wanting to send/receive messages it's up to you to do work so that the receiver doesn't e.g. merge multiple messages, only receive part of a message, etc. There's no guarantee of a 1-1 relationship between `Write` calls at one end and `Read` calls at the other.

Comment: I agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever. In addition instead of just blocking with read you can use the [NetworkStream.DataAvailable Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable?view=net-5.0) of the networkstream to verify if there is any data to be read. So you don't have to break your blocking `Read` call by closing the client. And to answer your original question - yes, it is to be expected as `Read` is blocking and so `Join` will not be able to finish.

Comment: Using the async API, you can probably opt out of using Threads explicitly and also, stopping (=cancelling) will become available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=net-5.0

Comment: @MarkusSafar Closing the client should close the stream, which - afaik - would interrupt the read by throwing an exception, shouldn't it?

Comment: Unrelated, just a tip: `Thread.Sleep(1 * 60 * 1000);` is aweful. You can use `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));`.

Comment: @Fildor: Yes, correct. Which is in my opinion not the best way to go ;-)

Comment: _"I mean is there a better way to check the connection than the way I have implemented here"_ - depends what exactly you want to check. If you want to check that very connection, best is to send some "Ping/Pong" over that connection. If you just want to know if the remote service is available and how it's doing, then mabe ["HealthCheck"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is for you.

Comment: @MarkusSafar I agree. Just - given you catch that exception, the Thread should end gracefully, right?

Comment: @Fildor According to your question: In my opinion yes. The thread should end either way - gracefully if the exception is caught and also if it is not caught. As far as my understanding on this topic goes `NetworkStream.Read` calls the `Read` method on the underlaying .NET `Socket` instance which itself calls the native `recv` method of the operating system socket. I am not 100% sure if closing the stream does indeed abort the native `recv` operation immediately. Probably there is the problem located...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Message framing might not be an issue for me as the connection is over the LAN. However, I do intend to look into it once I sort other things out.

Comment: @MarkusSafar I understand `Read` is blocking. But what is exactly happening when I put in timespan in `Join()` method? Is this better than `Abort()`?

Comment: @Fildor Async API is definitely an option but what I like about blocking call is I don't have to specify the interval for loop - just incase a message gets lost during that time. I might be wrong. Regarding connection check, I have had the connection idle out where client doesn't update. Like mentioned, server supports request/response api. So client can periodically send out request message to which server will reply. My question is, is there a better way to do it than the way I have implemented - e.g. calling a thread within a thread and using separate `NetworkStream` ?

Comment: @MarkusSafar I think you're right about closing the stream not aborting the native `recv`. This had be puzzled. Sometimes when I stopped the service and tried to restart immediately, I got following error, _"System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."_ This might be what you're referring to. It worked after sometime though.

Comment: @thethakuri "... better than Abort"- _never_ use Abort.

Comment: @thethakuri If you just call `Join()` it internally calls `Join(TimeOut.Infinite)` which will wait indefinitly. I imagine that with a timespan specified, it will probably check in a cyclic manner whether the time has expired or not. Basically it just tells you whether the thread has aborted within the specified timespan or not. If not, you receive false as a return value - that's all. I totally agree with Fildor here - you should never abort something if you can end it gracefully.

Comment: @thethakuri I would suggest you refactor your code to poll the  [`NetworkStream.DataAvailable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable?view=net-5.0) manually (like `if (!stream.DataAvailable) { Thread.Sleep(10); continue; }`) and handle the proper abort yourself by making it part of the condition in the loop or something like that.

Comment: @MarkusSafar If I use `NetworkStream.DataAvailable`, does the data just sit there in the stream till the client consumes them after 'waking up' ? Like I mentioned, I don't want to loose any updates from server while the client thread is sleeping.

Comment: @thethakuri Yes, from the docs: _Gets a value that indicates whether data is available on the NetworkStream to be read._ So you just get an indication whether data is available or not. Nothing will be read automatically or something in that way...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My messages have delimiter, namely ";" at the end of each message. Is there good reference on how to implement that for message framing?